# How to get max value and name from a Pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a series like the one below:

```
mySeries = pd.Series([1,2,3],['c','b','a'])
```

How do I go about getting the max value along with the name associated with it in a single line?  In this case: `a: 3`

I can get the max value with: `mySeries.max()`, the name of the max value with `mySeries.idxmax(axis=1)` but I can't figure out how to get both of those values with one line.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 12):

[**`pd.Series.nlargest`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html)

```
mySeries.nlargest(1)

a    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Wow so simple one

Comment: how to get the 'a' from this?

Comment: @kkica `.index()[0]` should work.

Answer (score 1):

One with boolean indexing (just an alternative) i.e

```
mySeries[mySeries.index==mySeries.idxmax()]
```

or

```
mySeries[mySeries == mySeries.max()]
```

or(Thanks @piRSquared)

```
mySeries[[mySeries.idxmax()]]
```

Output:

```
a    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: `mySeries[[mySeries.idxmax()]]`

Answer (score -1):

You could do:

```
foo.value_counts()[:1].index.tolist()[0]}
```